# Getting "Invalid" error on user login

Tags: php, mysql

I have table "user" then inside is column "user_name" and "password"

user_name = admin

password(hashed) = admin

```
<?php
    $message = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['user_name']));
    $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
    $hashed_password = sha1($password);

    if (empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $message = "You must enter username and password" . "<br />";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM user ";
        $query .= "WHERE user_name = '{$username}' ";
        $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        verify_database($result);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            redirect_to("content.php");
        } else {
            $message = "Invalid username or password" . "<br />";
        }

    }

}
```

?>

```
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <?php echo $message; ?>
            User Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"/><br />
            Password: &nbsp;  <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
```

The problem now is even I put the right username and password. I keep in getting "Invalid username or password".

Comment: I think `$password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));` could just be `$password = $_POST['password'];`

Comment: The way you have written that, you are leaving yourself open for a SQL injection attack.  If I entered a username of `'; DROP TABLE user; --` on your web form, it would delete your user table.  Please look at http://bobby-tables.com for more on this topic, and http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of how to safely use parametrized queries.

Comment: @AndyLester unless `mysql_prep()` does some escaping first

Comment: still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Off topic, but it's worth pointing out that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete. The PHP manual **strongly** recommends not using them any more and switching to either the `mysqli_xxx()` funcs or the PDO lib.

Comment: did u check the value for `$hashed_password` with the DB and see, if its the exact same value? Also, the length assigned to that column, to make sure its storing the entire hashed password?

Comment: I tried to remove $hashed_password to $password so the password is not hashed anymore. I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: coder1984 Thanks.
The problem is on the varchar(30) it should be varchar(40).

Comment: Then please remove this question as it won't likely help others.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
$message = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = trim($_POST['user_name']);
    $password = trim$_POST['password']);
    $hashed_password = sha1($password);

    if (empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $message = "You must enter username and password" . "<br />";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM user ";
        $query .= "WHERE user_name = '{$username}' ";
        $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        verify_database($result);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            redirect_to("content.php");
        } else {
            $message = "Invalid username or password" . "<br />";
        }

    }

}

 <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <?php echo $message; ?>
            User Name: <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name"/><br />
            Password: &nbsp;  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
```